# How to update npm in windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, github, npm

I am looking for a way to upgrade my npm, I follow the option 3 for windows in here [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm). but when I install it it said npm.exe already in nodejs folder. I try to overwrite it with --force but it still not overwritten. How to do it correctly? also how to update node?

Comment: Install latest node.js

Comment: yes i already have it

Comment: Doesn’t `npm i-g npm` work?

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: You should look at [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and let that manage your npm and node versions. Much easier for upgrading and switching

Comment: you read the docs first, then try to do the option 3 for windows, then read my detail. thanks

Comment: ohh ok the npm i -g is working, now how to update the node?

Answer (score 8):

This is the new best way to [upgrade **npm** on Windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade).

Run PowerShell as Administrator

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Note: Do not run `npm i -g npm`. Instead, use `npm-windows-upgrade` to update npm going forward. Also if you run the NodeJS installer, it will replace the node version.

- Upgrades npm in-place, where node installed it.
- Easy updating, update to the latest by running `npm-windows-upgrade -p -v latest`.
- Does not modify the default path.
- Does not change the default global package location.
- Allows easy upgrades and downgrades.
- [Officially recommended by the NPM team](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows).
- A list of versions matched between NPM and NODE (https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) - but you will need to download NODE INSTALLER and run that to update node (https://nodejs.org/en/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool, [nvm](http://nvm.sh), that solves your problem quite easly. There is also a [Windows version](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), is not as cool as the linux/mac version but it works fine anyway

Comment: nvm controls the version of node.js not npm.

Comment: It does control the version of npm too! you can try `nvm use lts; npm -v; nvm use latest; npm -v;`, in my case it says "8.15.0" and "8.19.2". You can also notice that changing the node version with `nvm use` hides all the the global npm packages previously installed (with -g), because there is one directory for each node version and it also contains the npm stuff

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using option 1. Go to environment system variables and add "%appdata%\npm" to path like this: [edit path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JubD.jpg)

Then updated npm files should be loaded before those you installed with node

Answer (score 0):

1. Node.js v16 or higher?

   ```
   npm install -g npm
   ```
2. Node.js v14 or below?

   ```
   Consider updating to latest LTS release of Node.js

   npm-windows-upgrade
   ```